# TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasError' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, jestjs

I am using jest for react native testing and I am using redux.While excuting the test file i got

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasError' of undefined

this error. I don't know how to send values to redux. Any one please Help me out.

The Error code is

```
FAIL  __tests__\jest\LoginScreen.test.js (6.801s)
  test
    × renders correctly (614ms)

  ● test › renders correctly

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasError' of undefined

      219 | const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      220 |     return {
    > 221 |         hasError: state.LoginReducer.hasError,
      222 |         error: state.LoginReducer.error
      223 |     }
      224 | }

      at Function.mapStateToProps [as mapToProps] (src/screens/login/loginScreen.js:221:38)
      at mapToPropsProxy (node_modules/react-redux/lib/connect/wrapMapToProps.js:54:92)
      at Function.detectFactoryAndVerify (node_modules/react-redux/lib/connect/wrapMapToProps.js:63:19)
      at mapToPropsProxy (node_modules/react-redux/lib/connect/wrapMapToProps.js:54:46)
      at handleFirstCall (node_modules/react-redux/lib/connect/selectorFactory.js:37:18)
      at pureFinalPropsSelector (node_modules/react-redux/lib/connect/selectorFactory.js:85:81)
      at Object.runComponentSelector [as run] (node_modules/react-redux/lib/components/connectAdvanced.js:43:25)
      at Connect.initSelector (node_modules/react-redux/lib/components/connectAdvanced.js:195:23)
      at new Connect (node_modules/react-redux/lib/components/connectAdvanced.js:136:15)
      at constructClassInstance (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:3716:20)
```

And My test code is

```
import "../jest";
import LoginScreen from "../../src/screens/login/loginScreen";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import configureMockStore from "redux-mock-store";
const mockStore = configureMockStore();

// Note: test renderer must be required after react-native.
describe("test", () => {
  let wrapper, store;
  beforeEach(() => {
    const initialState = {
      hasError: false,
      error: {
        display_message: "",
        data: null
      }
    };
    store = mockStore(initialState);
  });
  test("renders correctly", () => {
    const tree = renderer
      .create(
        <Provider store={store}>
          <LoginScreen />
        </Provider>
      )
      .toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is apparently nothing saved in your redux state called `LoginReducer`. Do you have a reducer with that exact name?

See the [`combineReducers`](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/using-combinereducers) guide on the official Redux docs to see how to use it. You'll need to use the `combineReducers` method to add `LoginReducer` to your state.

Answer (score 0):

@KevinCooper In combineReducer the did not mention about how to values in jest. I have the same doubt how to send values to redux store in jest